# Error cropping a base64 format image using jimp package in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, jimp

```js
var base64str="data:image/jpeg;base64,***"//base64 format of the image
var buf = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64');
  
jimp.read(buf, (err, image) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    image.crop(140, 50, 200, 280)
      .quality(100)
      .getBase64(jimp.MIME_JPEG, function(err, src) {
        console.log("rb is \n")
        console.log(src);
      })
  }
})
```

I am trying to use the jimp package from npm to crop the base64 format of an image but I am getting an error as follows:

```txt
Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (D:\Node\image-crop\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\utils\image-bitmap.js:108:15)
    at new Jimp (D:\Node\image-crop\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:425:32)
    at _construct (D:\Node\image-crop\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:100:393)
    at D:\Node\image-crop\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:932:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.Jimp.read (D:\Node\image-crop\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:931:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node\image-crop\index.js:46:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

Is there any way to crop an image which is in base64 format without converting it into an image in Nodejs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is from the base64 string. To make it work, just drop the prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, and just leave the data.

Example :

```
const base64str = "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="//base64 of a 1x1 black pixel
const buf = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64');

jimp.read(buf, (err, image) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    image.crop(140, 50, 200, 280)
      .quality(100)
      .getBase64(jimp.MIME_JPEG, function (err, src) {
        console.log("rb is \n")
        console.log(src);
      })
  }
})
```

Output is :

> rb is
>
> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA[...]